# Python: union of set of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have two sets:

```
t = {('b', 3), ('a', 2)}
r = {('b', 4), ('c', 6)}
```

I want a union on 1st element to result in

```
u = {('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 6)}
```

if duplicate symbol is present in both place (example 'b' in the above) then the element of the first list should be retained.
Thanks.

Comment: Why ('b', 3) and not ('b', 4)?

Comment: That's the specification, will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: It appears to me that you want a dict with `update` in reverse order of appearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do:

```
t = {('b', 3), ('a', 2)}
r = {('b', 4), ('c', 6)}
d = dict(r)
d.update(t)
u = set(d.items())
print(u)
```

Output:

```
{('c', 6), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)}
```

Comment: this method here is OP underrated move of the day, take my rep

Answer (score 2):

A little bit shorter version:

```
s = dict((*r, *t))
set(s.items())
```

Output:

```
{('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 6)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for el in r:
    if not el[0] in [x[0] for x in t]:
        t.add(el)

t 

{('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 6)}
```

Comment: efficiency is key else the question is very trivial I think

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with set intersecion. Two objects are either equal or they are not. Since your objects are tuples, `(b, 3)` and `(b, 4)` are not equal, and you don't get to change that.

The obvious way would be to create your own class and redefine equality, something like

```
class MyTuple:
    def __init__(self, values):
         self.values = values

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.values[0] == other[0]
```

and create sets of such objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one-line style solution based on comprehensions:

```
t = {('b', 3), ('a', 2)}
r = {('b', 4), ('c', 6)}

result = {*t, *{i for i in r if i[0] not in {j[0] for j in t}}}

print(result)  # {('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 6)}
```

Using conversion to dictionary to eliminate the duplicates, you can also do that, which is a quite smart solution IMHO:

```
t = {('b', 3), ('a', 2)}
r = {('b', 4), ('c', 6)}

result = {(k,v) for k,v in dict((*r,*t)).items()}

print(result)  # {('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 6)}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

t = {('b', 3), ('a', 2)}
r = {('b', 4), ('c', 6)}

result = set({k: v for k, v in chain(r, t)}.items())
```

**Output**

```
{('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 6)}
```